# angular7 with devextreme in visual studio 2017 not working

Tags: angular, npm, visual-studio-2017, devextreme

I have setup angular project in vs2017 with angular cli template.

Now i want to use devextreme with angular, so according to official documentation i have installed `npm install --save devextreme devextreme-angular`.

But i have got erroe not installed in npm dependencies like below image:

[image]

so how to solve this. i have tried to restore packages, but it not works.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console when you install?

Comment: it install correctly, no error..just showing not installed in npm dependencies.

Comment: If possible, please check if this document give any help: https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/Getting_Started/Installation/How_To/Add_DevExtreme_to_an_ASP.NET_Core_Angular_Application/

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT i have read that document. i have done exactly like this, but still showing devextreme not installed like in image