# which package to use for DevExtreme? npm or nuGet?

Tags: angular, npm, visual-studio-2017, nuget, devextreme-angular

I want to use DevExtreme with angular in vs2017.

According to DevExtreme Documentation, there is two option to use it:

> 1. npm package
> 2. NuGet package

so which one to use?? and why??

I am using Angular7 in visual studio 2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which package to use for DevExtreme? npm or nuGet?

You can use either of the two options. Personally recommend that you use `npm`.

That because **the usage of NuGet for css/javascript libraries is discouraged**, and the DevExtreme Documentation also said:

> We recommend using the `DevExtreme npm package` instead if you are
>   developing a modular application

When you use nuget, there are still some extra manual operations:

> After installing the NuGet package, you need to link the DevExtreme
>   stylesheets and scripts. Open your index page and add the links to the
>    tag as shown in the Local Scripts article.

And the NuGet package **contains only** `dx.viz.js`, `dx.web.js`, and `dx.viz-web.js`.

So, personally recommend that you use `npm`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: k i am agree with you. but using npm, i have some issues. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54630743/angular7-with-devextreme-in-visual-studio-2017-not-working  you have any solution?

Comment: @chirag, Yes, I saw it. Since above answer help you resolved this issue, you could accept it as answer, so that we could close this thread. And for the npm install issue, we will track it on that case. Thanks.